# If $a,b$ are positive integers such that $a^{n}+n$ divides $b^{n}+n$ for every $n$, then $a=b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I need help with this question.

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $a^{n}+n$ divides $b^{n}+n$ for every natural number $n$. Show that $a=b$.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You could try something along the lines of choosing $n$ such that $n$ is a prime not in the prime factorization of either of $a$ or $b$. Then use the fundamental theorem (arithmetic) to show $a=b$ is a necessary condition.

Comment: Thanks LPenguin. $a^p+p$ divides $b^p+p$, p prime, $gcd(a,p)=gcd(b,p)=1$

Comment: That means $k(a^p+p)=b^p+p$

Comment: For k is a natural number, k>1. (I am trying to prove by contradiction)

Comment: Therefore $ka^{p}+kp=b^p+p$

Comment: $(k-1)(a^p+p)=b^p-a^p$

Comment: This is congruent to b-a mod p

Comment: By Fermat Little Theorem

Comment: $(k-1)a$ is congruent to $b-a$ mod p

Comment: $ak$ is congruent to $b$ mod p

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988167/if-for-all-n-in-bbbn-an-n-divides-bn-n-then-a-b) is a near duplicate, and has a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main idea came to me when I have solved this problem is that, if we can show that any number which is greater than $b-a$ divides $b-a$, then we will have $b=a$. Let $p$ is a prime satisfies $\gcd(a,p)=1$ , $\gcd(b,p)=1$ and $p>b-a$. Consider $k$, any positive integer such that $p\mid k-a$. As, it is true for any natural number, consider a $n=k(p-1)+p$. Fermat's Little Theorem gives $$a^n \equiv a\equiv -k(p-1)\pmod{p} \implies p\mid a^n+n \mid b^n+n \\ \implies a^n \equiv b^n\pmod{p} \implies a \equiv b\pmod{p} \implies a=b$$

Comment: I figured out another solution. Let p be prime, and a divide p and let b not divide p. This way $a^p+p$ is divisible by p, but $b^p+p$ is not. Contradiction.

Comment: I came up with this two hours after I asked.

Comment: @Kai Well done, please accept the answer if this one fulfills what u have wanted, otherwise it will be treated as unanswered question and will come back to the top of question queue again and again!

Comment: Well I think my answer is right. I got it. It is an answered question.

Comment: @Kai You have posted some comments about your approach, it will be better to write then in the problem.